# How to find the duration from startTime and endTime [DateTime] through slick

Tags: scala, datetime, slick-3.0

I actually want to compute the duration and sort the results by descending order.

I have tried,

```
db.run(totalSuccess.sortBy(ele => computeDuration(ele.startedOn, ele.completedOn).desc))

private def computeDuration(d1: Option[DateTime], d2: Option[DateTime]) = (d1, d2) match {
    case (Some(d1),Some(d2)) => new Period(d1, d2, PeriodType.hours())
    case _ => None
}
```

Getting a type mismatch error where `ele.startedOn` is `Rep[Option[DateTime]` and `computeDuration` expects `Option[DateTime]`.

Will it work ? or is there any other simple way to do this.

Comment: No this will not work. You have to keep in mind DB IO actions in Slick generate SQL. Even though the API looks like standard scala code, you cannot use arbitrary types unless they are explicitly supported by Slick. In your case you have to define a Slick function for interval computation that will map to a native SQL function. Can you maybe post a complete code sample that compiles?

Answer (score 1):

Do it at the database level using database functions.

```
def diff(d1: Rep[DateTime], d2: Rep[DateTime]): Rep[Long] = {
  SimpleFunction.binary[DateTime, DateTime, Long]("datediff").apply(d1, d2)
}
```

replace `datediff` with appropriate database function for your database solution